# How can I see if a string contains values from a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2012, substring

So let's say I have 2 tables. One with strings and one with values.

1st table called `Strings`

```
  | StringField
1 | Hello, World!
2 | I have got
3 | A lovely bunch of coconuts
```

2nd table called `Values`:

```
  | ValueField
1 | bart
2 | Hello
3 | 3gs
4 | foop
5 | nch of

SELECT * FROM Strings
WHERE StringField --contains a value from ValueField in Values
```

In the query above, I should want to return rows 1 and 3 from the Strings table because row 1 contains "Hello" and row 3 contains "unch of".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, StringField
FROM dbo.Strings s
INNER JOIN dbo.[Values] v
    ON s.StringField LIKE '%' + v.ValueField + '%'
;
```

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL

```
SELECT strings.* 
FROM strings
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT upper('%' || valuefield || '%') AS pattern
    FROM values 
    WHERE id = 4
) AS valuespattern ON (valuespattern.pattern like upper(strings.stringfield))
```

SQLserver

```
SELECT Strings.* 
FROM Strings
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT upper('%' + ValueField + '%') AS pattern
    FROM Values 
    WHERE id = 4
) AS ValuesPattern ON (ValuesPattern.pattern like upper(Strings.StringField))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select S.StringField
from Strings as S
Join Values as V
on S.StringField like '%' + V.ValueField + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte_Strings
As
(   
SELECT 1 ID, 'Hello, World!' AS StringField  Union All
SELECT 2, 'I have got'                       Union All
SELECT 3, 'A lovely bunch of coconuts'
),cte_Values
As
(
SELECT 1 Id, 'bart' As ValueField   Union All
SELECT 2, 'Hello'                   Union All
SELECT 3, '3gs'                     Union All
SELECT 4, 'foop'                    Union All
SELECT 5, 'nch of'
)
SELECT  Distinct c1.* 
FROM cte_Strings c1
INNER JOIN cte_Values c2
ON CHARINDEX(c2.ValueField,c1.StringField)>0
```